# jQuery code works when a checkbox is selected but doesn't work when unchecked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gutenberg-blocks

I have a jQuery function that's suppose to change the color of `<div>` when it's checked. When it's not checked, there's no background. When it's checked, it's suppose to be black. It works when it's check but doesn't work when you uncheck it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
$(document).on('change', '#two_img_left_feature_img label.selected input', function () {
    if ($("#two_img_left_feature_img label.selected input").is(":checked")) {
        $('#two_img_left_feature_img').css('background','black');
    } else {
        $('#two_img_left_feature_img').css('background','white');
    }
});
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<div id="two_img_left_feature_img">
     <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_60173d68d2c6a-field_5f8cf27e7c048-two_img_left_set_featured_img" name="acf-block_60173d68d2c6a[field_5f8cf27e7c048][]" value="two_img_left_set_featured_img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about `label.selected`... When the checkbox is not checked, I guess the label does not have the `.selected` class.

So just remove `label.selected` from the event handler selector AND from the condition. It was just too specific...

```js
$(document).on("click", "#two_img_left_feature_img input", function () {
  if ($("#two_img_left_feature_img input").is(":checked")) {
    $("#two_img_left_feature_img").css("background", "black");
  } else {
    $("#two_img_left_feature_img").css("background", "white");
  }
});
```

```css
#two_img_left_feature_img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="two_img_left_feature_img">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_60173d68d2c6a-field_5f8cf27e7c048-two_img_left_set_featured_img" name="acf-block_60173d68d2c6a[field_5f8cf27e7c048][]" value="two_img_left_set_featured_img">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhhh, so simple!  Thanks.